# Server Not Working when trying to accees on another oc or placed client on other computer

Tags: java

[image]

[image]

how can i get ip for both server and ping

Comment: Are all the computers on the same network? If they aren't just try using the `ip address` you get by searching `whats my ip` on google.

Comment: Please do not just give a link add your problem here in the question and ask

Answer (score 0):

On the server pc, check Windows firewall. You probably need to allow incoming TCP/UDP connections to java.exe (if you want you can restrict the port range to 52075-52077 as per your screenshot), also the network profile must be 'private' or I think Windows will ignore your settings.